# Preg_replace if statements?

Tags: php

I have this code

```
$text = preg_replace('#\[if_dark\](.*?)\[/if_dark\]#is',if ($currentUser->skin == 'dark') { echo "$1"; },$text);
```

I'm trying to do so if the user viewing the presentation has the dark skin it will see the content, otherwise not.

Ofcourse it doesn't work but how do I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: you cant put the if\echo inside the preg_replace

Comment: Either use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), or use your `if` to wrap the content replacement - strip marker+text when the condition is false. (And because you'll probably later discover that you need more complex conditions: use a templating engine for such tasks).